# Setter of a singleton from an custome class in .Net C# not triggered if only one property changed

Tags: c#, .net, singleton, setter

I have this class

```
 public class SPP {

    static PPModel PP= null;

    public PPModel sPP
    {
        set
        {
            if (PP != value)
            {
               PP = value;
               //save PP in database
            }
        }
        get
        {

            if (PP == null)
            {
                //lazy loading of PP
            }
            return PP;
        }
    }
}

public class PPModel
{
    public string property1 { get; set; }
    public int property2 { get; set; }
    public int property3 { get; set; }
    public int property4 { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> property5 { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I set sPP in this way, everything works fine:

```
SSP.Instance.sPP = new PPModel(){...};
```

But I want to know if it is possible to just update one property of this singleton and trigger the setter in this way:

```
SSP.Instance.sPP.property4 = 7;
```

If I do it in this way, the singleton sPP has the updated value, but the setter seems not to be triggered what means the additional code like database save will not work.

Any chances to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a good solution for this is to change the model to have full properties definitions, and on the setters, call the DB update, as such:

```
public class PPModel
{
    private string _fieldOne;

    public string Property1
    {
        get { return _fieldOne; }
        set
        {
            _fieldOne = value;
            // update DB
        }
    }

    private int _field2;

    public int Property2
    {
        get { return _field2; }
        set
        {
            _field2 = value;
            // update DB
        }
    }

    // and so on for all properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger setter in your singleton by updating internal stored object properties.

You can trigger your setter like this:

```
SSP.Instance.sPP = new PPModel(){...};
var instance = SSP.Instance.sPP;
instance.property4 = 7
SSP.Instance = instance;
```

This way you'll reset the exact variable to your instance and trigger update.

But, as you're implementing singleton, it is NOT responsible for making actions related to the object it stores. 
You have to monitor changes in your PPModel object, as only this class is responsible for it's internal state.